# rollover a text hyperlink to become an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how can i do this?

is it possible to have a text hyperlink and once its hovered over, that text link becomes an image?

iv seen image rollovers but haven't seen or know how to code text to image rollover yet.

i just dont know where to begin and with what programming language. javascript? php? jquery?

i started of by using the following code:

```
<a href = "#" onmouseover = "(document.img.src)='SAM_2251.jpg';">Mouseover here</a>

<img name = "img" alt = "" border = "0" />
```

but what this does is it keeps the text on screen whilst the image is loaded below it. i want the text to completely get rid off by the image.

any help guys? thanks so much in advance.

Comment: not even Chuck Norris can do this with PHP, (that language is server-side)

Comment: Lol... May be David copperfield can do it.

Comment: @ajax333221: Chuck Norris can do a cross-domain ajax request without CORS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will make the link change to an image only when hovered, becomes text when hovering out (only CSS)

```
<style>
.changeable img
{
  display:none;
}
.changeable:hover span
{
  display:none;
}
.changeable:hover img
{
  display:inline-block;
}
</style>
<a href="http://www.example.com" class="changeable"><span>Hyper Text</span><img src="img.png" /></a>
```

Or if you want the link to permanently change to image (with jQuery)

```
<style>
.changeable img
{
  display:none;
}
</style>
<a href="http://www.example.com" class="changeable"><span>Hyper Text</span><img src="img.png" /></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.changeable').hover(function(){
  $(this).children('img').show();
  $(this).children('span').hide();
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using just html and a css background image:

html

```
<a href = "#" class="hover_image">Mouseover here</a>
```

css

```
a.hover_image:hover {
    background: url(/url/to/image) no-repeat center center;
    text-indent: -9999em;
}
```

You probably need a bit more css to define the width and height of the `a` tag, but this is the basics.

Answer (score 2):

You ca in do in a lots of ways, here is a CSS rough example, just to see the idea

[**try this**](http://jsfiddle.net/dd5ym/3/)

Comment: yh its nice but the text link contains a hyperlinked border! is there anyway i can remove that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming HTML similar to the following:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/image.png" class="textToImg">Some text</a>
```

The following JavaScript should work:

```
function textToImage(elem){
    if (!elem) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = elem.href;
        elem.removeChild(elem.firstChild);
        elem.appendChild(img);
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7cUEK/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a javascript way to do it

```
    <div id="link">    
    <a href = "#" onmouseover = "document.getElementById('link').style.display='none';document.getElementById('hoverImage').style.display='block';;">Mouseover here</a>  
</div>
<div id="hoverImage" style="display:none">
    <img name = "img" alt = "" border = "0" src="img.JPG" onmouseout = "document.getElementById('link').style.display='block';document.getElementById('hoverImage').style.display='none';;" />    
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, it works! how do i code it so when the mouse is not hovering over the image, the text comes up and the image dissappears?

Comment: I have edited the answer to include the feature for getting the text back.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done with jQuery:

<kbd>**[See In Action](http://jsfiddle.net/pkZAW/)**</kbd>

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$( function() {
  $("#imglink").hover(
    function () {
      $(this).attr('small',$(this).html());
      $(this).html($(this).attr('full'));
    },
    function () {
       $(this).html($(this).attr('small'));
    }
  );
});
</script>

<a herf="" id='imglink' full='<img border="0" src="someImage.png" width="163" height="37"/>'>Rollover for image 'n' rollout for text</a>

</body>
</html>
```