# rollover an image hyperlink to become an text line

Tags: html, css

I found this useful html as answer to a question about rollover image to text by renocor ([rollover a text hyperlink to become an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307606/rollover-a-text-hyperlink-to-become-an-image))

```
<style>
.changeable img
{
  display:none;
}
.changeable:hover span
{
  display:none;
}
.changeable:hover img
{
  display:inline-block;
}
</style>
<a href="http://www.example.com" class="changeable"><span>Hyper Text</span><img src="img.png" /></a>
```

but i needed to achieve the opposite effect. So i inverted span with image it partially works. Meaning that instead of the image i see the text but the problem is that the image doesn't disappear but shifts just below the text.

Any suggestions? 
Thanks

```
.changeable span
{
    display: none;
}
.changeable:hover image
{
    display: none;
}
.changeable:hover span
{
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
<a href="http://www.example.com" class="changeable"><span>Hyper Text</span><img src="img.png" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `<style>` and put img instead of image, worked for me.

```
.changeable:hover img
{
display: none;
}
```